# Json array in php code

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to use Json array in the php code. 
The problem is that I'm in a for loop and need to separate the array in 2 and then want to merge it. but so far it didn't work.
I use it to have a graph (jqxChart).

Here is my code

```
for($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++){
   if ($i%2 == 1){  
    $time[$i] = (hexdec($hour[$i]));
    $orders1[] = array(
            'OrderDate' => $time[$i],
        );
   }else{ 
    $hour[$i] = $hour[$i] + 1;
    $orders2[] = array(
             'ProductName' => $hour[$i],
    );
  }
}
$orders[] = array_merge_recursive( $orders1[], $orders2[] );

}

echo json_encode($orders);
```

Thanks

Comment: How about just `$orders = array_merge($orders1, $orders2)`?

Comment: I try this too but it give the same result

Comment: array_merge_recursive( $orders1[], $orders2[] ); is incorrect. The [] operator after a variable is for assignment. You should only be using the brackets if a = is following the expression. By doing $orders[] = array_merge... You are *appending* the array merge results to $orders, not assigning them. P.S. sorry for the lack of code styling. I'm on my iPad :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,

```
$orders1 = array();   
$orders2 = array();  
for($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++){
  if ($i%2 == 1){  
    ....
    $temp1 = array(
            'OrderDate' => $time[$i],
        );
    array_push($orders1, $temp1);
   }else{ 
    ....
    $temp2 = array(
             'ProductName' => $hour[$i],
    );
     array_push($orders2, $temp2);
   }
  }
}
$orders = array_merge( $orders1, $orders2 );
echo json_encode($orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets. Instead of:

```
$orders[] = array_merge_recursive($orders1[], $orders2[]);
       ^^                                 ^^          ^^
```

Just put:

```
$orders = array_merge($orders1, $orders2);
```